# i was using hive then system automatically shut down after that unable to open hive

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, hive

unable to open apache hive in ubuntu. I am using hadoop2.9.0. actually, I have done all the procedure for installing hive. i was using automatically system getting shut down, then I open system after that unable to open hive.

Comment: any error log to include?

Comment: go to hive logs and paste the log output here. Then only we will be able to help you.

Comment: at.org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:165)atorg.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:157)atorg.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95)at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:359)at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy32.mkdirs(Unknown Source)atorg.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.primitiveMkdir(DFSClient.java:2540... 18 more

Comment: Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/home/shipra/Desktop/hadoop/apache-hive-2.1.0-bin/lib/hive-common-2.1.0.jar!/hivelog4j2.properties Async: trueException in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException: Cannot create directory /tmp/hive/shipra/7e907e3d-10a9-4d64-aa7f-9e7e79d1f415. Name node is in safe mode.The reported blocks 2599 needs additional 1 blocks to reach the threshold 0.9990 of total blocks 2603.